# Have crawler index private pages while hiding the content?

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers, prerender

I've got a whole e-book of key word rich original material that i want to add to my site to help boost the search engine rankings. The problem is that I don't want anyone to be able to view these pages but I still want search engines to crawl them. This is necessary because e-book content is proprietary.

If someone should type into the search engine the specific string of text found on one of my pages, I don't want Google to display that page as a search result but maybe give link to the page where it can only be unlocked by login and purchase of a ebook page.

I have been looking at Prerender.io to see if it's possible to render a scrabbled version when requested by crawler. I'm not sure how this will play with the authentication process in the Express.js middleware before routing to the actual e-book content page. I'm thinking server can give out different version of a page depending on if user or crawler requested the ebook page.
but is this even possible? Or Are there any suggestions or different design to what I'm trying to achieve?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer is: Don't do this, don't even try.

Google has spent the better part of two decades making sure people cannot fool their crawlers, you are not going to be able to trick them by some server settings. Trying to serve different content to the crawler than to normal users will at best not work and at worse flag your site as suspicious and directly harm your SEO.

If you want to leverage your content, then make sure to have publicly available excerpts, summaries and reviews. These are things that users will want to see anyway if they are going to buy the products and they are great for SEO, but don't try to make Google index things that are normally behind a paywall.